# How to run a script when opening OpenBox?

Tags: server, scripts, 16.10, openbox

On my Ubuntu Server computer, after I log in (in tty1), I can run `startx` which opens Openbox.

I want to run a specific command when opening Openbox.

How can I do that?

I did it in the past and I found a solution on a forum, but I can't seem to find the page anymore.

Comment: http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Autostart may offer some pointers?

Comment: @DKBose Ah, correct! It turns out I already have a script there but probably it fails. Can you post an answer? It may help others later. Thanks!

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu Server. Just regular Lubuntu's Openbox session and so I don't know enough about your system to post an answer. If you figure out things, may be you could post the correct procedure as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it doesn't exist, create a file in your `~/.config/openbox` directory called `autostart` or `autostart.sh` (both should work).  If the openbox directory doesn't exist, create that as well.

In this file, you put in all your executables that you want to run when openbox starts.  Ensure you put an ampersand after every command, otherwise, openbox will lock up waiting for the executable to end.

Here is an example of an autostart file:

```
tint2 &
plank &
volti &
```

As you can see, with the ampersands, the autostart script will be able to continue executing the next lines.

If you would like to see more on how to completely setup an openbox desktop, including running applications in the autostart file, [see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxWRZuKqmk4)

Comment: is there no way to pass something via command line? this approach is not very nice for multiple openbox instances

Comment: @Blauhirn What do you mean by "pass something"?  If you mean command line switches, then yes, you can just add them between the command and the ampersand.  For example `command --option something &`

Comment: I was referring specifically to Openbox. Imagine you'd want to start two openbox instances. First one should open up tint2 and second one should start plank (or a terminal or any other program). To automatize, you would have to modify autostart.sh every time automatically, possibly making a backup of it beforehand. That works but is clumsy. It would be great to have something like `openbox tint2` and `openbox plank` right away. No such thing, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Another approach could be: 1st: Start openbox, 2nd: wait until display is ready, 3rd: start desired program on that display. Also works, but 2nd step is complicated and also more like a workaround.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to start 2 instances of Openbox though, since it's a Window Manager that handles everything.  It supports multiple displays and multiple desktops.  You can have tint2 open on only one display or desktop if you wish.  But if you would like multiple instances, you could run it as a 2nd user which would have its own ~/.config folder for another set of autostart processes.